# Is it possible to retrieve TypeInfo from a string using the new Delphi's RTTI library?

Tags: delphi, rtti, typeinfo

I'm wondering if this is possible. I want to get the `TypeInfo`, passing the type's name as a string.

Something like this:

```
type
  TSomeValues = record
    ValueOne: Integer;
    ValueTwo: string;
  end;


function ReturnTypeInfo(aTypeName: string): TypeInfo;
begin
    // that's is the issue
end;

procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _TypeInfo: TypeInfo;
begin
  _TypeInfo := ReturnTypeInfo('TSomeValues');
end;
```

Comment: Use the docs: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`TRttiContext.FindType()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext.FindType) method and [`TRttiType.Handle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.Handle) property, eg:

```
uses
  ..., System.TypInfo, System.Rtti;

function ReturnTypeInfo(aTypeName: string): PTypeInfo;
var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Typ: TRttiType;
begin
  Typ := Ctx.FindType(aTypeName);
  if Typ <> nil then
    Result := Typ.Handle
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

...

type
  TSomeValues = record
    ValueOne: Integer;
    ValueTwo: string;
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  _TypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
begin
  _TypeInfo := ReturnTypeInfo('Unit1.TSomeValues');
  ...
end;
```